# upgrade program - missing keypair

Tags: program, upgrade

Is it possible to upgrade a program to the same programId even though I dont have the generated keypair.json file anymore? Can the keypairfile for the programId be recreated any how?

Answer (score 4):

If you specify an update authority for your program then the initial program keypair is not needed for future deploys. If using Anchor this is handled for you.

```
solana program deploy --program-id ./program-keypair.json program.so
solana program set-upgrade-authority PROGRAM_ID \
  --upgrade-authority ./program-keypair.json \
  --new-upgrade-authority ./program-update-authority.json
```

Now you just need the `program-update-authority.json` keypair for each deploy.

https://docs.solana.com/cli/deploy-a-program#set-a-programs-upgrade-authority

Comment: I'm holding the upgrade-authority of the contract:

solana program show 97NuFLguKsp64phr1LnwevVREfuVzENfKAHzi5dHEJr8

Program Id: 97NuFLguKsp64phr1LnwevVREfuVzENfKAHzi5dHEJr8
Owner: BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111
ProgramData Address: 89CQ3rNnZGkB5Z4QCse8LVQzhXTckzofRW3vK7Evvaes
Authority: 7nhQbEA4RUc1QzNfzz2EuuWEZBnu4D54iTsALnxo8j2Q

but if I redeploy the same progam I get a new programId:

solana program deploy --upgrade-authority 7nhQbEA4RUc1QzNfzz2EuuWEZBnu4D54iTsALnxo8j2Q deploy/program.so
Program Id: 48cQ74oujkuXUgZon7i96WtFvetLP2boKR6uuYhyJmYB